# Checkbox not change checked value from keydown event but also still be able to focus and tab to the next element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Checkbox input that looks like:

`<input name="checkbox_1" type="checkbox" aria-disabled="true" checked />`

I am using CSS to prevent the click events but using `e.preventDefault();` with `keydown` event listener does not let me tab to the next element after I hit that checkbox. Is there anyway I can solve this?

Edit: Forgot to add handler code.

```
checkboxList.forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Could not find a solution from other posts, most likely has been answered I assume. Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you using `pointer-events: none`? That definition could be tricky sometimes, especially with interaction events.

Comment: @MihailMinkov Correct, that's exactly what I am using! :)

Comment: You're preventing the default action of all keys, you've to extract the tab key outside.

Comment: How do I do that? But shouldnt the tab be a focus event and the keydown not prevent that? @Teemu

Comment: The tab key is a key as any other key, changing focus is its default action. Just check `if (e.key !== 'Tab') {e.preventDefault();}`.